# Duda sobre paginación en Laravel

Tags: laravel, paginación

Estoy usando la paginación de Laravel para mostrar unos datos en una tabla y todo anda bien, el problema es que al usar los botones que proporciona el método "link()" para cambiar de página, manda por url la página "page=2", pero yo estoy utilizando otras variables también por URL y al cambiar de página se pierden. ¿Cómo puedo modificar las variables que se mandan al cambiar de página para mantener mis variables?.

Comment: Muestra lo que llevas hasta el momento

Comment: Puedes personalizarla fácilmente a tu gusto, te dejo también el enlace a la documentación {{ $users->appends(['sort' => 'votes'])->links() }} {{ $users->fragment('foo')->links() }} https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination

Comment: tenes que capturar las variables ya sea usando el request o definiendolas en la ruta

Answer (score 0):

Si lo haces desde blade en el formulario agrega appends con al request->query para que persistan todos tos parámetros.

```
{!! $messages->appends(request()->query())->links('your view') !!}
```